# TypeError: uniqueCategories.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, map-function

I'm new in Next and Typescript and can't solve the issue, I have tried all possible options that found in the internet and thinking maybe the problem is that the answers were old and something have changed....

I'm getting this error in my restaurant website project while trying to make a categories filter for menu .
I was supposed to get categories from menu. I use Set to get unique categories from menu data and then I make an array from object uniqueCategoriesSet
(I just read in the internet that it can solve the issue with "TypeError: uniqueCategories.map is not a function " but it doesnt).
Before this I was just passing unuqieCategoriesSet to CategoriesButtons as a prop and there was the same issue and also another issue in CategoryButtons component: "Parameter 'uniqueCategoriesSet' implicitly has an 'any' type."

I'm using framework Next and Typescript

I really appressiate any help!

page.tsx:

```
"use client"
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { menu } from '../data'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import CategoryButtons from '../components/CategoryButtons'

const MenuPage = () => {
  const uniqueCategoriesSet = new Set<string>();
  menu.forEach(item => {
    uniqueCategoriesSet.add(item.cat);
  });
  const uniqueCategories: string[] = Array.from(uniqueCategoriesSet);
  return (
    <div className='p-4  '>
      <h1 className='text-center'>Menu</h1> 
      <CategoryButtons {...uniqueCategories}/>
      <div className=" flex flex-wrap">
        {menu.map(item=>(
        <div className=' w-full h-[60vh] flex flex-col items-center justify-center border-2 sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4'>
          <div className='relative h-[60%] w-full '>
            <Image src="/fruit-salad.png" alt="" fill className='object-contain'/>
          </div>
          <div className='p-4'>
            <h1 className='font-bold'>{item.title}</h1>
            <p>Desc</p>
            <span className='font-bold'>Price</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default MenuPage
```

CategoryButtons.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'


const CategoryButtons = (uniqueCategories:string[]) => {
    console.log(typeof(uniqueCategories));
  return (
    <div className='flex items-center gap-2 h-12'>
        <button className='bg-green-600 p-1 text-sm text-white rounded-md'>All</button>
           {uniqueCategories.map((item)=>(
            <button className='bg-green-600 p-1 text-sm text-white rounded-md'>
                {item}
            </button>
       ))}
    </div>
    )
}
export default CategoryButtons
```

```
my data - menu:
interface Menu  {
        id: number;
        cat: string;
        title: string;
        desc?: string;
        img?: string;
};


export const menu:Menu[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        cat: "starters",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        cat: "starters",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        cat: "main",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        cat: "main",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        cat: "drinks",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        cat: "drinks",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        cat: "desserts",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        cat: "desserts",
        title: "Fruit salad",
        desc: "Strawberry, banana, avocado",
        img: "/fruit-salad.png",     
    },
]
```

I just want to press buttons (CategoryButtons component) of menu categories (drinks, Main courses etc..) and be able to filter menu (MenuPage page)

I have tried passing a Set uniqueCategoriesSet to a CategoryButtons
Because I thought that the issue is that map function doesnt work with objects i decided to make an array from the unuqueCategoriesSet
I have tried passing an Array uniqueCategories to a CategoryButtons
(and i checked type of uniqueCategories, it is an object...)

I have tried changing the way I pass unuque Categories to CategoryButtons:
`<CategoryButtons {...uniqueCategories}/> <CategoryButtons <CategoryButtons uniqueCategories={uniqueCategories}/>`

I have tried to change parameters in CategoryButtons conponent:
`const CategoryButtons = (uniqueCategoriesSet)  const CategoryButtons = (uniqueCategoriesSet:[string])`

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(typeof(uniqueCategories));`?

Comment: @TheMaster object

Comment: Hello @PolinaTea, Can you share your code (even if its just partially) in https://codesandbox.io/ . I tried just the bit where you're creating the Set and converting it into an Array and trying to map over it. It seems to work for me.

Comment: Also, What's the output of `console.log(Array.isArray(uniqueCategories));`?

Comment: managed to fix the problem this way (Taking values of the unique Categories in map function):   {Object.values(uniqueCategories).map((item,id)=>(
            <button key={item} className='bg-green-600 p-1 text-sm text-white rounded-md'>
                {item}
            </button>
       ))} But maybe you guys know of a better way to solve it? for me it seems as a weird solution

Comment: @dina the output of console.log(Array.isArray(uniqueCategories)); is "false"

Comment: That is correct. The props passed to a component is always of type `object` and is not an Array. Answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77324052/6068959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things that needs to be corrected in your code. Firstly, the functional component `CategoryButtons` accepts props which is always of type object. You cannot pass the `uniqueCategories` array directly. It has to be one of the properties in the props object. Note that it can be named anything. Example below:

```
import React from "react";

interface CategoryButtonsProps {
  uniqueCategories: string[];
  otherProps: Int; // other props example
}

const CategoryButtons = (props: CategoryButtonsProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center gap-2 h-12">
      <button className="bg-green-600 p-1 text-sm text-white rounded-md">
        All
      </button>
      {props.uniqueCategories.map((item) => (
        <button
          key={item}
          className="bg-green-600 p-1 text-sm text-white rounded-md"
        >
          {item}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CategoryButtons;
```

And in the `page.tsx` file, you would pass the props as shown below:

```
<CategoryButtons uniqueCategories={uniqueCategories} />
```

Hope it helps! [here's a link to the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/clever-paper-gklyhy) where I solved your problem.

Comment: Ref: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Comment: I did everything the same as you, but it doesnt work for me...."CategoryButtons.tsx:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: @PolinaTea Did you check this link? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/clever-paper-gklyhy

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? probably its a different issue now if you have followed the instruction above.

Comment: Yes, checked sandbox and I have everything the same as you have. Getting another error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') The above error occurred in the <NotFoundErrorBoundary> component:

Comment: your solution works! I checked my code again and found a mistake (I accidentially deleted string where I make an array from a Set) Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I come from Vue rather then React, but the spread on the component looks odd.

<CategoryButtons {...uniqueCategories} />: In this line, you are spreading the uniqueCategories array into the CategoryButtons component. However, you should pass an array as a prop, not spread its values. To pass an array as a prop, you should do it like this:

```
<CategoryButtons categories={uniqueCategories} />.
```

In the CategoryButtons component, make sure it handles the categories prop correctly. You can then map over the categories array to render buttons.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this already. Doesn't  solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should send the props like:

```
<CategoryButtons uniqueCat={uniqueCategories}/>
```

What is sent is a object with property `uniqueCat`. Read it like:

```
const CategoryButtons = (o:object) => {
  const uniqueCategories = o.uniqueCat;
  console.info(Array.isArray(uniqueCategories))
```

Alternatively destructure it:

```
const CategoryButtons = ({uniqueCategories}) => {
  console.info(Array.isArray(uniqueCategories))
```

Ref: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Comment: I get this error if i send props this way: Type '{ uniqueCategories: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
  Property 'uniqueCategories' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.ts(2322)

Comment: @PolinaTea Which method `const CategoryButtons = ({uniqueCategories}) => {`?